# Openshift PHP7 wordpress app throws “404 Page not found error” with custom domain name

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have a wordpress app based on [PHP7 catridge](https://m.do.co/c/ca790c346da7) on Openshift. I added two alias to the app(e.g, www.xyz.com & xyz.com) and I also updated the CName in my Zone file. When I enter www.xyz.com, it redirects me to www.xyz.com/app and throws a 404 NOT FOUND error (nginx/1.11.6).

But I can access the administration page without any problem (www.xyz.com/wp-admin)

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Enter the www.domain.abc first. Use CloudFlare to configure your domain. Make things pretty easy.

**After this you will get the pretty permalinks error related to ngnix.**

I am too getting the same error. I can access the home page and most of the things. This error only arises when I decide to use Pretty Permalinks in WordPress.

Till now I have figured it out that we have to edit the ngnix file. But there are several files out there.

Has made me even more confused.

**This may not be the solution but you can access post and other stuff in plain permalinks.**